# How to send input to stdin from code not terminal?

Tags: c++

I want to send input to a variable without having to type it in the terminal, as i am implementing a test case. for example consider the input to be sent is 2:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

The code should not wait for the user to give input, it should enter 2 there and populate a by itself.

i cant use the cin buffer, also taking input is compulsory.

Comment: `yourprogram < somefile.txt`

Comment: I cant do that either.

Comment: Can you mock the cin object? Maybe gmock can do that for you. (Haven't checked but it's the first place I'd look).

Comment: You can use a [stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) filled with a test case, and read from that instead of from cin.

Answer (score 1):

you could create unnamed pipes pipe pd[2] and dup stdin & stdout to the pipe fds.
then write "2" into one pipe and read it from another.

Comment: While your answer seems correct, the lack of correct punctuation makes it hard to read and understand. Also it may be too short to be easily understandable for the original poster. Example code and more explanation may be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The basic question here (at least in my mind) is whether you're trying to write a single program, so that one part of the program provides the input to another part of the program, or you're writing two separate programs, one of which provides input to the other.

@Madhu Narayanan has already given a good summary of how you'd go about writing the code for the first case.
But, by far the preferable way to handle things inside a program is to have something like a function that takes (a reference to) an iostream as a parameter, so you can pass `std::cin` to read from the console, or some `stringstream` to have it read some predetermined data instead.

If what you care about is the second case, then you'd probably want to use `popen` (or Microsoft calls it `_popen`), which will spawn a child process, and connect a pipe to either its standard input or its standard output (but, regrettably, not both). So if this is what you want you'd do something like this:

```cpp
// spawn the child, getting a handle to its standard input:
FILE *child = popen("child program", "w");

// write the input to the child:
if (child != nullptr) {
     fprintf(child, "%d", 2);
}
```

For better or worse, there's no analog of this that gives you access to the child via an `iostream` (at least, not a pre-written one in the standard library, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your input from a stringstream instead:

```
std::stringstream data = "2";
int a;
data >> a;
```